# Why using $v^T \cdot u\text{ instead of simply } v \cdot u$?

Tags: notation, vectors

I know they are equivalent, but why and when should we prefer using $v^T \cdot u$ instead of simply $v \cdot u$, when $v$ and $u$ are vectors of $\mathbb{R}^m$, for example?

Comment: Note that the two dots are different: The first one is matrix multiplication, while the second one is the dot product.

Comment: A vector is a $n\times 1$ matrix. You can't multiply two such matrices, since the number of columns of the first must be equal to the number of rows of the second.

$$(n \times 1) \cdot (n\times 1) \tag{not valid} $$
$$(n \times 1) \cdot (1\times n) \tag{valid}$$

Answer (score 1):

It tells you things like $(Au)\cdot v = u \cdot (A^Tv)$